# Get location (coordinates) periodically without dramatically increase battery consumption

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationmanager, android-location, battery-saver

I'm developing an Android application; this App needs to send periodically (every 10 minutes) the current position (coordenates) to a web service. But ... I'm a little confused about the more correct way (and friendlier to the device battery) to do that.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669068/4359029) and her method `_getLocation()` looks well; but I don't know whether that method could get the availability of the location I need; total availability...

I would like, if the location is not available using GSM / WIFI, application choose the GPS method.

Is that what makes this method?

```
private void _getLocation() {
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }
}
```

Anybody know one way to get the coordinates of the device periodically... without dramatically increase battery consumption?

Comment: If you are worried about battery consumption and so worried about getting your location updates a bit late, you should check the PassiveProvider. It's piggybacking on other apps who use the Location Services.

Comment: Before all; thanks for your comment. And yes, I'm so worried about this things. May you give me a example for `PassiveProvider`?

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the most battery-efficient approach of using LocationClient to periodically get updates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139866/whats-the-most-battery-efficient-approach-of-using-locationclient-to-periodical)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139866/whats-the-most-battery-efficient-approach-of-using-locationclient-to-periodical/17155460#17155460

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are worried about battery and not so stricted on the 10 minutes interval you could try to use PassiveProvider instead of GPS/Coarse.
Usually other applications request locations often enough so you don't need to worry about it.
If you are strict, than you could try to ask for location yourself in case one hasn't received in the past interval.
Here is an example for using the Passive Provider.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Do work with new location. Implementation of this method will be covered later.
        doWorkWithNewLocation(location);
    }
};

long minTime = 10*60*1000;
long minDistance = 0;

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
```

Comment: This snipet will get the coords even when the phone is suspended?

Comment: What do you mean by phone is suspended? if the location services is off you will not get location updates. You can still register the locationListener but it will not be called.

Comment: Hi @Ohad, thank you for your reply, what do I meant was: blank screen, locked screen, black screen, idk the correct term for it... like when u press the shutdown button, the screen will turn off, but my phone still on.

Answer (score 3):

Play Services has a Low Consumption location API. You can found more info in [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) you can found a example of Play Location Service stored in Github. Look the [LocationUpdates](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates) example.

When you setup you Location Request you can change the priority, see more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#location-request). I think that you use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`

Comment: Thanks for your help @ClarkXP. May I ask you about the comment of @Ohad Zadok? Is your example better than `PassiveProvider` with respect to the battery saving and location availability of the devices?

Comment: @tomloprod I think that Play Services is more easy to setup and more efficient to manage the location sources and energy draining. See my update

Comment: I don't agree, since the PassiveProvider does not start the GPS on it's own, it doesn't use energy at all.

Comment: @OhadZadok This feature may be a problem when other location sources are unavailable, if the location is not available using GSM / WIFI, Play Service can activate the GPS provider, ensuring the application functionality.

Comment: That is correct, and he'll have to cover that case. But in my experience for 10 minutes interval and low accuracy this rarely happens.